# multiple animation blocks not working

Tags: ios, animation, cgaffinetransform

I'm trying to translate and scale a view in the same block.  For some reason the translate code is over riding the scaling and setting it at 100%.  Please help.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                        delay:0.0 
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{                              
                         fullView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 425.0);
                         fullView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8); 
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) { }];
```

SOLUTION - Change 2 transform lines into one with CGAffineTransformConcat:

```
fullView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 425.0), CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transform` is a property that you are setting and then re-setting.  What you need to do is construct a `CGAffineTransform` that consists of a combination of the two transforms.  `CGAffineTransformConcat()` should nicely help you with that.

Comment: That's the ticket.  Thank you!